# IsEnabled if value exists in other list

Tags: c#, wpf

I have trouble understanding how to disable `TextBox` if value doesn't exist in my other list.
I've got two lists (`Users` and `Admins`). I'm displaying a list Users in `ListView` where I've got all users and I want to set a property `IsEnabled` to `false` if the given user/item doesn't exist in another list (my list: `Admins`).

In XAML I've got:

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Users}" x:Name="myListViewExample">
   <ListView.View>
      <GridView>
         <GridViewColumn Header="name">
            <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
               <DataTemplate>
                  <TextBox d:DataContext="d:DesignInstance {x:Type model:User}}" Text="{Binding name, Mode=TwoWay, NotifyOnValidationError=true}"/>
               </DataTemplate>
            </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
         </GridViewColumn>
         <GridViewColumn Header="login">
            ´<GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
               <DataTemplate>
                  <TextBox d:DataContext="d:DesignInstance {x:Type model:User}}" Text="{Binding login, Mode=TwoWay, NotifyOnValidationError=true}" IsEnabled="{Binding ???}"/>
               </DataTemplate>
            </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
         </GridViewColumn>
         <!--...other columns-->
         <GridView>
   </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

In model:

```
private List<User> admins;
public List<User> Admins
{
    get { return admins; }
    set {
        admins = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged(() => Admins);
    }
}
```

Comment: Do both `Users` and `Admins` lists change independent from one another?

Comment: if i delete item from Users list i delete this same user from list admins.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both `Users` and `Admins` have in common that they are lists with items of type `User`, which seems redundant, since being an admin should be a property of a `User`. Duplication seems odd here.

Suppose you add a property `isAdmin` to your `User` model or create a separate wrapper model with such a property eliminates your issue.

```
public class User
{
   // ...other fields, methods or properties.

   public string name { get; set; }

   public string login { get; set; }

   public bool isAdmin { get; set; }
}
```

Then you can simply bind `IsEnabled` to the `isAdmin` property.

```
<TextBox d:DataContext="d:DesignInstance {x:Type model:User}}" Text="{Binding login, Mode=ToWay, NotifyOnValidationError=true}" IsEnabled="{Binding isAdmin}"/>
```

I kept the property names camel cased here, but following common code conventions in C#, you should make properties pascal cased (beginning with a capital letter), e.g.: `Name`, `IsAdmin`, ...

---

This is an example of a wrapper for `User` (this time Pascal-Cased with `INotifyPropertyChanged`).

```
public class UserViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
   private readonly User _user;

   public UserViewModel(User user, bool isAdmin)
   {
      _user = user;
      IsAdmin = isAdmin;
   }

   public string Name
   {
      get => _user.name;
      set
      {
         if (_user.name == value)
            return;

         _user.name = value;
         OnPropertyChanged();
      }
   }

   public string Login
   {
      get => _user.login;
      set
      {
         if (_user.login == value)
            return;

         _user.login = value;
         OnPropertyChanged();
      }
   }

   public bool IsAdmin { get; }

   public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

   protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
   {
      PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
   }
}
```

---

Since you specifically asked for a converter, I will provide one as a **proof of concept**, but **I do not recommend** to do this, since it is inefficient and there are much better alternatives, see above.

You could create a multi value converter, that takes two bound values, first a concrete `User`, second an `IEnumerable<User>`. It will check if the user is contained in the collection. I compared the `name` of both users here, because I guess it is unique and I do not know if you implemented equality operators in your `User` type or if both `Users` and `Admins` contain the *same* `User` instances which is required if you would compare references. Please adapt it to your needs.

```
public class ContainsUserConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{
   public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
   {
      if (values == null || values.Length != 2 || !(values[0] is User user) || !(values[1] is IEnumerable<User> users))
         throw new ArgumentException("The provided values are invalid.");

      return users.Any(u => u.name == user.name);
   }

   public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
   {
      throw new InvalidOperationException("This conversion is invalid.");
   }
}
```

In XAML you have to instantiate the converter and use it in a `MultiBinding`.

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Users}" x:Name="myListViewExample">
   <ListView.Resources>
      <local:ContainsUserConverter x:Key="ContainsUserConverter"/>
   </ListView.Resources>
   <ListView.View>
      <GridView>
         
         <!-- ...other columns. -->

         <GridViewColumn Header="login">
            <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
               <DataTemplate>
                  <TextBox Text="{Binding login, Mode=TwoWay, NotifyOnValidationError=true}">
                     <TextBox.IsEnabled>
                        <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource ContainsUserConverter}">
                           <Binding/>
                           <Binding Path="DataContext.Admins" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ListView}}"/>
                        </MultiBinding>
                     </TextBox.IsEnabled>
                  </TextBox>
               </DataTemplate>
            </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
         </GridViewColumn>
      </GridView>

      <!-- ...other columns. -->

   </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

Comment: i can't add property in user class because it is from json from other aplication. I have to be consistent. My list admins will always be very small and I need two lists.

Comment: @jrJerry Is it possible for you to add a wrapper class, e.g. `UserViewModel` with a property `IsAdmin` and use that one instead? Internally it could just use the `User` class.

Comment: if that's better then i think yes but maybe some converter ?

Comment: @jrJerry I have added examples for both, but **I do not recommend** the value converter.